# How to extract information from text in r and create new column?

Tags: r, string, extract

There is a column in my data with information about a product:

"Technical Details Manufacturer recommended age:14 years and up Manufacturer reference176-1308 Scale1::160 Track Width/GaugeNo    Additional Information ....".

How do I extract only age from that text and put it in a separate column?

The expected output would be the number after `"age:"`, `14`.

Probably I need to use package `stringr` and try function `str_extract` but it not clear how to realise that.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
s <- "Technical Details Manufacturer recommended age:14 years and up Manufacturer reference176-1308 Scale1::160 Track Width/GaugeNo Additional Information ...."

sub(".*age:(\\d+).*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "14"
```

- `(\\d+)`: Capture one or more digits

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are simpler regular expressions but this one seems to work.

```
s <- "Technical Details Manufacturer recommended age:14 years and up Manufacturer reference176-1308 Scale1::160 Track Width/GaugeNo Additional Information ...."
s

sub(".*age[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]*).*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "14"
```

If you want the output as a number,

```
num <- sub(".*age[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]*).*", "\\1", s)
num <- as.integer(num)
num
#[1] 14
```

You can do the above in one step, `num <- as.integer(sub(etc))`.